# How to properly support multiple languages? (And should my app do so?)

Tags: android, design-patterns, database-design

I've read a fair bit about localization on Android, but I've yet to find a single guide on how to implement localization at scale. The Android platform provides fairly extensive coverage for static apps - however, what if my app uses multiple online services that do not have multi-language support but do have (a very large set) of constant values that could reasonably be translated? Should this be done?

For example, I have an app that shows flight data and uses a service that only has support for two languages. If I wanted, I could add all flight statuses (Delayed/On-Time/Final/Boarding/etc), all cities and all countries to a few tables on an internal app database.

I have not calculated how much storage space this will take, but my guess is - this will require quite a bit of storage. Is the tradeoff worth it? I could also maybe launch my own service and query it, but I feel this may be a very expensive solution that only enterprises can afford.

Comment: your question will be seen as too broad by a lot of people (i didn't downvote, i'm just saying). you have to consider who will be using your app and if you need to use localization firstly

Answer (score 0):

Most of localisation services just store strings and help Android/iOS teams to sync it. I don't think what it's necessary to implement your own service. For example you can use POEditor or Lokalize.

Preparing:
You get all keys from Android/iOS app and load it with values in string localisation service.

About localisation on scale:
When team work at some feature programmers load new strings in service (keys and for example English version) and send request for translation (for example Chinese, German, Spanish etc).

When translators answers what translation ready and loaded to localisation service you sync this strings, see differences in git and check for potential bugs.

Hope it'll help